# How is comparison to oneself made?

Tags: word-usage

I wanted to translate the following English:

> These are facts which, with the self-evident proposition that no being can create another being superior **to itself**, smashes your silly hypothesis to nothing.”

This was my attempt:

> Diese sind Tatsachen, die mitsamt dem selbstverständlichen Lehrsatz, dass kein Wesen ein anderes erschaffen könnte, das ein Besseres **als sich selbst** sei, Ihre doofe Hypothese zu nichts zerstören.«

But I was corrected with:

> Diese sind Tatsachen, die mitsamt dem selbstverständlichen Lehrsatz, dass kein Wesen ein anderes erschaffen könnte, das ein Besseres **als es selbst** sei, Ihre doofe Hypothese zu nichts zerstören.«

DWDS shows examples of both of these 2 ways of making comparison to oneself:

> Schwerer **als sich selbst** war es für sie, ihre Umwelt zu überzeugen.

> Ein Modell für mehr **als sich selbst** sind all diese liebenswerten Halb-, Viertel- und Vollaussteiger aber nicht.

> Sie wird beantwortet durch die Angabe dessen, was ein jegliches **als es selbst** ist: seiner Washeit.

> Im Phaidon hatte Platon über die ousia ausgesagt, sie sei das, was ein jegliches Seiendes **als es selbst** ist

How does one choose from the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on case: *sich* is the accusative of *es*.

> ... das ein Besseres **als es selbst** sei...

Copulas (*A ist B*) use nominative case, thus it must be *es*.

> Schwerer **als sich selbst** war es für sie, ihre Umwelt zu überzeugen.

*überzeugen* governs the accusative case, thus *sich*

> Ein Modell für **mehr als sich selbst**

*für* uses the accusative, too, thus *sich*

> was ein jegliches **als es selbst ist**
> was ein jegliches Seiendes **als es selbst ist**

Again, copulas

Answer (score 4):

The difference comes down to the cases:

**nominative**

> *jemand* (wer/was) + sein -> etwas besseres als **er/sie/es** sein

**genitive**

> sich *jemandes/etwas* (wessen) schämen -> Ich schäme mich **meiner selbst**

**dative**

> *jemandem* (wem) + geben -> ich gebe es jemand besserem als **mir selbst**

**accusative**

> *jemanden* (*wen/was*) überzeugen -> ich überzeuge **mich selbst**
> für + *jemanden* (*wen/was)* -> Ein Modell für **sich selbst**

This stays the same if your object contains a comparison, so there's not really anything special concerning them. If you have difficulties nontheless, because the sentence becomes more complex, just try to formulate the sentence without a comparison first, so you might get a better feeling/idea what case to use, and then substitute in the actual comparative construction.